# php- allow special characters Â Ê Ç

Tags: php, regex

i have a problem in my php because i'm trying to get a value from a table and the value has special characters like "Ã;-;Ê" i´m using this line of code

```
preg_replace('/[^,a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\s]/', "", $row["name"]);
```

but this doesn´t allow me to use Ã Ê or Ç.

can u please adjust my code to work please.
thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at PHP's regexp unicode support: http://php.net/manual/pl/regexp.reference.unicode.php

Comment: already did and it didn´t help me

Comment: Well your regular expression is too restrictive, so make it less restrictive by adding more characters to the character class.